# How to iterate HashMap<String, ArrayList<Car>>

Tags: java, hashmap

How to print ArrayList from HashMap?

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Car>> cars = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Car>>;

ArrayList<Car> carList = cars.get("bmw");

    for (int i = 0; i < carList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(carList.get(i));
    }
```

The code causes:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Despite the "bmw" key exists and is populated.

Comment: why don't you use `iterator` ?

Comment: Much better than `iterator` is the enhanced for loop (assuming you are using JDK 1.5 or more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in a

```
System.out.println(cars.get("bmw"));
```

to check and see what exactly is in it (in the Map, and the ArrayList of cars).

Comment: ugh.. The key should begin with capital letter. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator<String> itr = carList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
      String element = itr.next();
      System.out.print(element + " ");
    }
```

Inoder to do this carList  should not be a null value.
To add values to ArrayList you can use

```
carList.add("Some value");
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to iterate through your list is to use foreach:

```
ArrayList<Car> carList = cars.get("bmw");  
for (Car car : carList) {
    System.out.println(car.getYourValueToPrint());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to iterate over ArrayList will be via enhanced for each loop which saves you the pain of a `NullPointerException`:

```
ArrayList<Car> carList = cars.get("bmw");
for(Car car: carList){
    car.doAnyOpertation();
    System.out.println(car.getAnyValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Car> carList = cars.get("bmw");
for(Car car: carList){
    car.doAnyOpertation();
    System.out.println(car.getAnyValue());
}
```

Even in this if carList is null, then line
`for(Car car: carList)` with throw NPE